# Docker container breaks localhost connection with CSF installed

Tags: docker, cloudflare, configserver, csf

I've been at this for 2 days now and can't wrap my head around it.

I have installed Docker on my server running WHM. Within Docker I have installed listmonk.app.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                   PORTS                                       NAMES
0eb46a14e3c2   listmonk/listmonk:latest   "./listmonk"             20 hours ago   Up 9 minutes             0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp   listmonk_app
43b308157ebe   postgres:13-alpine         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago   Up 9 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:9432->5432/tcp, :::9432->5432/tcp   listmonk_db
```

Next up, I installed a Cloudflare Tunnel to allow access via `https://listmonk.ygprodeck.com` to `http://localhost:9000`.

This works until I installed ConfigServer Security and Firewall (CSF) on the server. Port 9000 is blocked in this (not added via `TCP_IN` or `TCP_OUT`) which is what I would want but now my Cloudflare Tunnel cannot connect to the docker container as it times out.

On the server, I ran `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:9000`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:9000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Disabling CSF fixes the issue, but then these ports are exposed, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Yesterday, Instead of using CloudFlare Tunnel, I used an Apache Reverse Proxy with basically the same end result.

Additionally, I attempted to add `docker0` to `ETH_DEVICE_SKIP` which just opens port 9000 externally to the world (I believe this just causes it to skip the firewall rules altogether).

I found a [Stack question](https://serverfault.com/questions/831770/after-centos7-upgrade-docker-services-not-reachable-anymore) that could possibly be similar but I am not overly familiar with Docker. With listmonk.app, I used the [easy production install](https://listmonk.app/docs/installation/#production).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

x-app-defaults: &app-defaults
  restart: unless-stopped
  image: listmonk/listmonk:latest
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  networks:
    - listmonk
  environment:
    - TZ=Etc/UTC

x-db-defaults: &db-defaults
  image: postgres:13-alpine
  ports:
  networks:
    - listmonk
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<REMOVED>
    - POSTGRES_USER=<REMOVED>
    - POSTGRES_DB=<REMOVED>
  restart: unless-stopped
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U listmonk"]  
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 6

services:
  db:
    <<: *db-defaults
    container_name: listmonk_db
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: listmonk-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    <<: *app-defaults
    container_name: listmonk_app
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./config.toml:/listmonk/config.toml
      
  demo-db:
    container_name: listmonk_demo_db
    <<: *db-defaults

  demo-app:
    <<: *app-defaults
    container_name: listmonk_demo_app
    command: [sh, -c, "yes | ./listmonk --install --config config-demo.toml && ./listmonk --config config-demo.toml"]
    depends_on:
      - demo-db

networks:
  listmonk:

volumes:
  listmonk-data:
```

I will also include the listmonk.app config.toml file but I think that mostly needs to be kept as is:

```
[app]
# Interface and port where the app will run its webserver.  The default value
# of localhost will only listen to connections from the current machine. To
# listen on all interfaces use '0.0.0.0'. To listen on the default web address
# port, use port 80 (this will require running with elevated permissions).
address = "0.0.0.0:9000"

# BasicAuth authentication for the admin dashboard. This will eventually
# be replaced with a better multi-user, role-based authentication system.
# IMPORTANT: Leave both values empty to disable authentication on admin
# only where an external authentication is already setup.
admin_username = "<REMOVED>"
admin_password = "<REMOVED>"

# Database.
[db]
host = "listmonk_db"
port = 5432
user = "<REMOVED>"
password = "<REMOVED>"

# Ensure that this database has been created in Postgres.
database = "listmonk"

ssl_mode = "disable"
max_open = 25
max_idle = 25
max_lifetime = "300s"

# Optional space separated Postgres DSN params. eg: "application_name=listmonk gssencmode=disable"
params = ""
```

Comment: In docker-compose if you want to expose port only to Docker host machine instead of `- "9000:9000"` use `- "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Docker and Cloudflare Tunnel client

You did not mention how you deployed the Cloudflare Tunnel client. As you already deployed `listmonk` via Docker, it only makes sense to do the same with the CF Tunnel client and use a shared Docker network for both services.

With the following compose file, you add a CF Tunnel client to the existing docker network `listmonk`:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  listmonk:
    external: true

services:
  cloudflaretunnel:
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared
    environment:
      - TUNNEL_TOKEN=$TUNNEL_TOKEN
    command: tunnel --no-autoupdate run
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - listmonk
```

The benefit is you don't need to expose `listmonk` service on `0.0.0.0:9000` where your firewall can interfere. Also, `0.0.0.0` meaning you're allowing remote connections. So you can get rid of:

```yaml
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
```

in the listmonk compose file.

([link to cloudflared Docker image on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudflare/cloudflared))

#### What about Cloudflare Tunnel client and a Firewall?

[From the documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/deploy-tunnels/tunnel-with-firewall/):

> You can implement a positive security model with Cloudflare Tunnel by
> blocking all ingress traffic and allowing only egress traffic from
> cloudflared. Only the services specified in your tunnel configuration
> will be exposed to the outside world.

You only need to allow outbound connection on port `7844`:

> cloudflared connects to Cloudflare’s global network on port `7844`. To
> use Cloudflare Tunnel, your firewall must allow outbound connections
> to the following destinations on port `7844` (via `UDP` if using the `quic`
> protocol or `TCP` if using the `http2` protocol).

Comment: The CloudFlare tunnel was indeed not installed through Docker! I'll try this and revert back!

Comment: Amazing! This worked. I needed to add the cloudflare tunnel server to the docker compose file like you say.  Works with port 9000 still closed!