Accessing Kafka broker through cloudflared tunnel
I'm trying to access kafka broker set up on a different network from my local machine through cloudflare zero trust tunnels. As mentioned in the Arbitary TCP in Cloudflare Documentation it should be possible to publish data to my localhost:29092 and forward that to the tunneled domain finally to the kafka broker.
The following is the docker-compose for the kafka
services:
   zookeeper:
     container_name: zookeeper
     image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
     environment:
       ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
       ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
     ports:
       - 2181:2181

   kafka:
     container_name: kafka
     image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
     depends_on:
       - zookeeper
     ports:
       - 9092:9092
       - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "kafka", "9092"]
       interval: 30s
       timeout: 10s
       retries: 5

`
I connected the local client on my local machine to the tunnel as mentioned in the documentation
cloudflared access tcp --hostname <domain> --url localhost:29092
But when I try to connect to the broker using kafkacat,
kafkacat -b localhost:29092 -L
it outputs
%3|1718482965.859|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:29092/bootstrap]: localhost:29092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:29092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT) %3|1718482966.858|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:29092/bootstrap]: localhost:29092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:29092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed) % ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure

Maybe this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77956028/docker-container-breaks-localhost-connection-with-csf-installed/77969536#77969536
